# Logistic regression without using for loop

Tags: r

I have 202×500 matrix that contains data for 200 variables in 500 people(data1.txt). y is binary data(0=control, 1= case)

```
 case y x_1 x_2 X_3 x_4・・・・x_200
 1   1  
 2   0
 3   1
 4   0
500  0
```

I would like to make logistic regression for x_1 to X_200（only one variable and no covariates) using R.
y~X_*, data=sample,family=binomial(*=1・・200)
Are there any easy way to run this analysis not using for loop?

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want a explicit loop, you could use `map` from the `purrr` package. This will do what you want. Below is example code based on your info. Probably not the best code, but should get you started. The glms are stored in the `my_glms` list object. More info read the vignettes of `purrr` and `broom`.

```
library(purrr)
sample <- data.frame(Y = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                     x_1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                     x_2 = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))


my_glms <- map(sample[,-1], #remove Y otherwise glm also on Y
               ~ glm(Y ~ .x, data = sample, family = binomial))

#using the tidy function from broom
library(broom)
map(my_glms, tidy)

$x_1
         term   estimate std.error     statistic   p.value
1 (Intercept) -206.12214  365130.9 -0.0005645158 0.9995496
2          .x   45.80492   80643.9  0.0005679899 0.9995468

$x_2
         term   estimate std.error     statistic   p.value
1 (Intercept) -251.92706  445370.6 -0.0005656572 0.9995487
2          .x   45.80492   80643.9  0.0005679899 0.9995468
```

Of course all this can be done in 1 line of code but this shows the steps and you can adjust where needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I want only y~x_1,y~x_2,y~x3,・・・X200 each P values,95%CI.not
y~x_1+x_2+・・・x_200

Comment: @ko0101, have you tried the code? the results in the list are Y ~ x_1, Y ~ x_2, etc. I added a bit of code to show the outcome using `tidy` from the `broom` package.